# MySQL add 0 when < *.10

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't seem to find/create a working query which will update the x column with an extra zero when value after the dot is below .10 - I've got column x with values;

```
7.3
5.3
0.14
```

I am trying to update the column so when the value after the dot is below .10 it adds a zero, above example will eventually need to look like;

```
7.03
5.03
0.14
```

Is there a way I can do this using an mysql UPDATE-query?

Many thanks.

Comment: `.3` is not less than `.10`! Your example is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get idea behind such operation but it's pretty simple.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN INSTR(id, '.') = 0 THEN id
    ELSE CASE
         WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED) < 10 THEN
               CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '.', 1), '.0', CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED))
         ELSE id
    END
END as result
FROM table_name


UPDATE table_name SET id = CASE
    WHEN INSTR(id, '.') = 0 THEN id
    ELSE CASE
         WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED) < 10 THEN
               CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '.', 1), '.0', CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED))
         ELSE id
    END
END
```

But before using this, think once again about your schema and what are you trying to do. I don't think you'll need this then.

Comment: This indeed gives the output I'm searching for, thank you. Is there a way to update the column so it will update the '7.3' to '7.03'?

Comment: @MoonDev Yes, change from `SELECT` to `UPDATE` is very easy. I hope you know how to do it?

Comment: I tried that haha, but when I do that I'm getting the Mysql error "for the right syntax to use near (..) WHEN CAST(SUBST' at line 1"

Comment: @MoonDev Can you show that code?

Comment: I tried the code you posted, but changed the table_name and select statement.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 0.03 is not equal to 0.30, so i believe what you want is 7.30 and not 7.03. To do this, you need to alter your table column to display two decimal digits:

`my_magic_column float(3,2)`

where 3 is the total number of digits and 2 is the number of decimals to show.

Comment: I understand it's not equal to 0.30. Though I'm trying to find a UPDATE query which sets the '7.3' to '7.03'.

Comment: alright mate, your question was a bit misleading

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you want to do is:

```
update TABLE set YOUR_NUMBER = (FLOOR(NUMBER) + (NUMBER-FLOOR(NUMBER))/10)
where FLOOR(NUMBER*10) = NUMBER*10
```

`FLOOR(NUMBER)` - take the integer part and add to it:

`(NUMBER-FLOOR(NUMBER))/10` - the fraction part of the number - divided by 10

The `where` condition checks that there's only one digit after the dot